# How to transpose a vector of vectors in Rust?

Tags: vector, rust

So I have a `Vec<Vec<T>>` where the first vector groups by hours of day and the inner vector by days of week. I would like to transpose somehow the vectors to have it first by days then by hours. Is there a simple way to do it in Rust?

EDIT: I mean, I know how to do it with 2 for loops but is there a smarter/shorter way to do it functionally

Comment: Please explain more clearly "the first vector groups by hours of day and the inner vector by days of week". What is `T`, maybe a `DateTime`? Can you show an example of input with the desired output?

Comment: It doesn't matter. Let's say it's T as in the answer

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use some iterators:

```rust
fn transpose<T>(v: Vec<Vec<T>>) -> Vec<Vec<T>>
where
    T: Clone,
{
    assert!(!v.is_empty());
    (0..v[0].len())
        .map(|i| v.iter().map(|inner| inner[i].clone()).collect::<Vec<T>>())
        .collect()
}
```

As `user4815162342` comments, here is a version without `Clone`:

```rust
fn transpose2<T>(v: Vec<Vec<T>>) -> Vec<Vec<T>> {
    assert!(!v.is_empty());
    let len = v[0].len();
    let mut iters: Vec<_> = v.into_iter().map(|n| n.into_iter()).collect();
    (0..len)
        .map(|_| {
            iters
                .iter_mut()
                .map(|n| n.next().unwrap())
                .collect::<Vec<T>>()
        })
        .collect()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b8df2ae16603a57e27ba645fc7c62b80)

Comment: Since the number of values is the same, it would be nice to have a version that doesn't require `T: Clone` - perhaps by draining the inner vectors.

Comment: Nice edit! I've come up with [this idea](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0fb46244d1ca2881b5e6b05b77d1839d) that first reverses the inner vectors and then pops them off the end, but a vector of into_iters is much nicer, and faster.

Comment: Does this functionality exist in a popular library somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

The question says *"I know how to do it with 2 for loops but is there a smarter/shorter way to do it functionally"*, however that it is probably the best answer for the title. Here's a two-`for`-loop solution that avoids `T: Clone` and avoids allocating a scratch `Vec` for iterators:

```
fn transpose<T>(original: Vec<Vec<T>>) -> Vec<Vec<T>> {
    assert!(!original.is_empty());
    let mut transposed = (0..original[0].len()).map(|_| vec![]).collect::<Vec<_>>();

    for original_row in original {
        for (item, transposed_row) in original_row.into_iter().zip(&mut transposed) {
            transposed_row.push(item);
        }
    }

    transposed
}
```

Someone could probably make it more "functional" than I, but this is already a bit difficult to read, try as I might.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way

```
let v = vec![vec![1,2,3,4], vec![5,6,7,8]];
let rows = v.len();
let cols = v[0].len();

let transposed: Vec<Vec<_>> = (0..cols).map(|col| {
    (0..rows)
        .map(|row| v[row][col])
        .collect()
}).collect();
```