# Most efficient implementation of Python zip in Rust for iterator of unknown length (Iterator<Item=Vec<String>>) at compile time

Tags: rust

I have a `Iterator<Item=Vec<String>>`, and the number of `Vec<String>` in the iterator is unknown at compile time.

The data structure looks similar to this.

```rust
[
    ['ABCD', 'EFGH', 'IJKL', ...], // Length of these Vec<String> will always be equal, but
    ['MNOP', 'QRST', 'UVWX', ...]  // unknown at compile time.
    ...
]
```

Out of this iterator, I need to get an iterator that looks something like this:

```rust
[
    ['ABCD', 'MNOP', ...],
    ['EFGH', 'QRST', ...],
    ['IJKL', 'UVWX', ...],
    ...
]
```

So essentially what I'm looking for is an implementation of Python `zip`.

```py
a: List[List[str]] = list()
b = zip(*a)
```

Comment: To read the first element of the output iterator, you need to exhaust the whole input iterator. Because of that you can simply collect the iterator into a `Vec<Vec<T>>`, and transpose the `Vec` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64499219/1600898). (The Python snippet effectively does the same - the `*a` in function call collects `a` into a tuple.)

Comment: @user4815162342 Yeap, this is exactly what I needed. Do we have a version without the clone?

Comment: @Netwave Yes, this is what I was looking for. In terms of efficiency, do we have a better implementation?. I'm dealing with terabytes of data, so every bit counts

Comment: @Shane, just updated my other answer with an owning version of the function ;)

Comment: @Netwave, that made a ~15% difference in runtime. Thanks!

Comment: BTW if you're dealing with terabytes of data, individual string allocations might be a bottleneck. Consider using `[u8; 4]` (if the strings are really  all 4-characters long and all-ASCII) as the inner type instead, or even represent the strings as `u32`, process them as numbers, and convert them back to strings only on output.

Comment: @Shane, awesome! nice to help! :)